# What type of database would you suggest for a large scale delivery company? RDBMS or NoSQL?

Tags: database-design, nosql

I've been learning the fundamentals of RDBMS and NoSQL systems. To start I thought NoSQL would be the way to go because of how large scale it could become, but understanding the importance of RDBMS ACID properties I'm now thinking this would correct because of regular customer transactions.

Can anyone give me any food for thought? I assume large companies may even use both types for different purposes

Comment: What's "large scale" for some is peanuts for others. What's _your_ large scale? Besides, there's no such thing as a "database for a company". It's always a "database for a specific application". What's your application?

Comment: @mustaccio it's just theoretical. I'm thinking along the lines of a company like Fedex so I guess an application for customer transactions, or an application for shipping info

Answer (score 2):

Transactional data that is highly structured is a perfect fit for relational databases.  It's not a matter of scale, it's a matter of what fits your data.  NoSQL databases are for unstructured (or highly variable) data.

Comment: This! NoSQL DBMS aren't inherently faster than RDBMS (or any other type of DBMS) for that matter when generically talking about amount of data and scale. They each have their own use cases they fit best for, and can each equally handle vast amounts of data when appropriately implemented.